# PugJs - template file not found / directory ignored

Tags: node.js, pug, pugjs

I have a simple application that should output a small content. I use **NodeJs, Express and Pug**.

```
const pug = require('pug');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const indexFile = 'index'; // the file to load

app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // use pug

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(indexFile, { templateToLoad: 'Views/Templates/temp.pug' }); // include a template file
});

app.listen(8888, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 8888');
});
```

And my Pug file / HTML

```
doctype html
html
    body
      p default content on all pages
      include templateToLoad
```

My directory looks this

[image: dir]

When starting the server I receive this error message

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\views\templateToLoad.pug'
    at C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\views\index.pug line 5
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:491:33)
    at Function.read (C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:69:13)
    at Object.read (C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:147:25)
    at C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:24:25
    at walkAST (C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:23:18)
    at C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:104:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:103:18)
    at walkAST (C:\Users\mah\Desktop\Test\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:37:19)
```

but when debugging `templateToLoad` I get `'Views/Templates/temp.pug'`. Why does the folder `Templates` get ignored?

Comment: try changing  `Views/Templates/temp.pug` to `./View/Templates/temp.pug`

Comment: no sorry, it's the same error message

Comment: sorry it seems its relative to the `index.pug` - try `./Templates/temp.pug` (or `/Templates/temp.pug`)

Comment: hmm no sorry, same error message :/ even `Templates/temp.pug` did not work

Comment: maybe I have to use the `path` module?

Comment: give me a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic includes are [not supported](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1955) in pug.
I suggest you to send template name and use [conditionals](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) in your index.pug to show required template.

Note : `temp1`, `temp2` ... `tempN` needs to be exist in your `Templates` folder

```
doctype html
html
    body
      p default content on all pages
      if templateToLoad == "temp1"
        include Templates/temp
      else if templateToLoad == "temp2"
        include Templates/temp2
```

Send template name.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(indexFile, { templateToLoad: 'temp1' }); // include a template file
});
```

Comment: so this is almost similar to my code, it is not possbile writing something like this here `Templates/ + templateToLoad`

Answer (score 1):

Did some digging around - It seems that pug does not support for dynamic includes (which you are trying to do here)

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/569

possible workarounds include using `jade.render` or re-using `res.render` with in itself to generate templates.

- [workaround-to-dynamic-includes-in-pug-jade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826063/2903169)
- [use-a-variable-in-a-jade-include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133319/2903169)

Answer (score 1):

Pug proposes Template inheritance https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html

So instead of rendering index.pug, you render your template :

index.pug :

```
doctype html
html
  body
    p default content on all pages
    block content
```

temp.pug :

```
extends index.pug
block content
  p My template
```

your server.js

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('temp');
});
```